# - Titanium - basic create new window

Tags: window, titanium

I have a newbie for Titanium. I try to create new page but i found error

> [ERROR] :  Script Error = Can't find variable: module at newCard.js (line 21).
>   [ERROR] :  Script Error = 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ti.include("ui/common/newCard.js").createWindow') at FirstView.js (line 46).

it's my test code

```
    function FirstView() {  
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();  

    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'black',
        text:String.format(L('welcome'),'(test)'),      
        top:'50',
        align:'center',
        height:'auto',
        width:'auto'
    });
    self.add(label);

    var txtClick=Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:String.format(L('txtclick'),'- click here -'),
        color:'red',
        top:'180',
        align:'center',
        height:'auto',
        width:'auto'        
    });
    self.add(txtClick); 

    var show=Ti.UI.createImageView({
        top:'100',
        width:'172',
        height:'52',
        image:'/images/logo.png' 
    });
    self.add(show); 

    txtClick.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
       var window = Ti.include("ui/common/newCard.js").createWindow({
        title:"new card a day"
       });
       window.open({
            animated:true
       }); 
    });

    return self;
}
module.exports = FirstView;
```

and cardNew.js

```
        function newCard(){
        var self = Ti.UI.createView({
            backgroundColor: 'black',
        });

        var show=Ti.UI.createImageView({
            top:'100',
            width:'172',
            height:'52',
            image:'/images/logo.png' 
        });
        self.add(show);

        return self;
    }
module.exports = newCard;
```

please help me.
Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your code to this inside the eventlistener's callback:

```
var newCard = require("ui/common/newCard");
var win = new newCard();
win.open({animated:true});
```